# Why does entity framework skip one of my tables?

Tags: entity-framework

Entity framwork made a entity for each of my tables except for one, and I'm not sure why. I select it when i generate it from the database.

Here is my entity framework diagram, and the diagram in SQL:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ18h.jpg

Notice how RecipeMeal is missing from entity framework. Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

RecipeMeal is supposed to store if a recipe is breakfast, lunch etc. It's not a column of Recipes because a recipe could be a lunch OR dinner recipe, as an example.

I am using EF 5.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework has built-in support for many-to-many relationships.

The table is exposed through the two `ICollection<T>` properties in `Meal` and `Recipe`.

Comment: This. Many to many join tables are not expressed through a separate table in the designer, but handled via mapping relationships (even though a separate table is generated).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. This is how I'm getting recipes that match a certain type:          `var typeResults = db.Recipes.Where(x => x.Type == type);`  How would I get the recipes that match breakfast or lunch in this setup? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Khepri Also, why do I have a recipeIngredients table then, since that is also many to many relationship?
Thanks again, just trying to understand.

Comment: @user1308743#1: `db.Recipes.Where(r => r.Types.Any(t => t.Name == x || t.Name == y))`

Comment: @user1308743#2: Entity Framework has built-in support for many-to-many relationships, but SQL Server does not.  The database needs the extra table, but the model doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in both posts. There is a manytomany table called recipeingredents that DOES show in entity framework.

and for the first comment i made... let me try and re explain the data i am trying to get back.
I'm trying to get recipes back from the recipes table,  but only recipes that have a mealid in the RecipeMeals that match the id in _id_meals for "lunch"

Answer (score 1):

I also found that if your table doesn't have a primary key it will also get skipped.  One of my tables was just a summary table and didn't really need a primary key and it wouldn't be included in the reverse engineer.  As soon as I added a primary key it was picked up.